# Detener un ciclo sin acabar el programa

Tags: python

Hola mi pregunta es la siguiente hay una forma de detener un ciclo sin cerrar el programa?
Por ejemplo tengo un programa que imprime varias veces una palabra que el usuario introduce

```
palabra = input()
while loop:
   print(palabra)
```

se imprimiría así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mientras sigue imprimiendo poder presionar alguna tecla o algo y regresar al input, para introducir una nueva, sin terminar el programa, sé que puedo crear un input dentro del loop pedirle que, si desea continuar, pero no quiero que se deje de imprimir la palabra

Comment: Hay varias opciones, ya sea usar un hilo, pedir el input luego de haber pasado determinado tiempo, usar alguna librería como `pynput`, etc.

Comment: usar una funcion, usar otro ciclo por fuera de este... creo que podemos estar todo el dia nombrando formas... la respuesta es si...

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, hay varias maneras de hacerlo solo que tienes que adaptarlo tomando en cuenta que es lo que quieres lograr.

```
def loopWhile():
    palabra = input("Ingresa una palabra: ")
    contador = 0
    while True:
        contador += 1
        if contador == 99999999999999999999999:
            contador = 0
            respuestaValidacion = input("Continuar con el programa? S =  Si / N = No ")
            if respuestaValidacion == 'S':
                print("---")
                continue
            elif respuestaValidacion == 'N':
                break
            else:
                print("Debes ingresar una de las opciones")
                print("---")
                continue
        elif keyb.is_pressed('shift+s'):
            palabra = input("Ingresa una nueva palabra a mostrar: ")
            print("---")
        elif keyb.is_pressed('b'):
            break
        print(palabra," ",contador)
        print("---")
```

Este ejemplo es utilizando la librería [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), este nos da acceso al teclado y utilizando la combinación *shift+s* o la tecla *b* realiza ciertas acciones el código, el contador solo es una referencia. También puedes utilizar un hilo como referencia el cual cada 5 minutos se vuelva a ingresar una nueva palabra o con fechas donde cada inicio de semana a las 8:00am vuelva a pedir una palabra, depende que es lo que necesites.

Espero y te sirva como referencia este ejemplo.